# How to Parse String to Date Using Date.TryParseExact

Tags: .net, vb.net, parsing, date

reading
`Dim lendingtimedate As String = If(irequest.Form.Contains("startingtimedate"), irequest.Form("endingtimedate").Value, "")`

getting value : `lendingtimedate = "04/23/2014 12:45 PM"`

and now i will to parse it in

```
Dim edateValue As Date
```

as

```
Dim enddate = Date.TryParseExact(lendingtimedate, "MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, edateValue)
```

but enddate is always: `edateValue = #12:00:00 AM#`

please help me to find out why i cant get

```
edateValue = "04/23/2014 12:45 PM"
```

Comment: Replace `Dim enddate =` with `Dim parsedSuccessfully As Boolean =` because it's more readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because there are no seconds in `"04/23/2014 12:45 PM"`, so this does not work:

```
"MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt"
```

but this:

```
"MM/dd/yyyy h:mm tt"
```

Answer (score 4):

`TryParseExact` returns a `Boolean` indicating whether the parse succeeded or not, so you need to test for the result.

In your case it is returning False because your format string did not match the format of the string you are trying to parse (you have an extra `:ss` that is not required).

The following code parses correctly:

```
Dim lendingtimedate = "04/23/2014 12:45 PM"
Dim edateValue As Date

If Date.TryParseExact(lendingtimedate, "MM/dd/yyyy h:mm tt", Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, edateValue) Then
    Debug.WriteLine(edateValue)
Else
    Debug.WriteLine("Failed to parse")
End If
```